# What is the difference between these 2 definitions in T4Mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

In my razor view I have the following:

```
   var url = "@Url.Action(Mvc.Leads.GetAllLeads())"
   var url2 = "@Url.Action(Mvc.Leads.Actions.GetAllLeads())"
```

They both appear to generate the same Url.  Why the actions property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no. The Actions property is there for backward compat with a really early version of T4MVC. But it may be better to yank it altogether now to avoid confusion.

Comment: I'll get rid of it in the next version.

Comment: Turns out it was needed after all, so I restored it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625462/t4mvc-actions-token for details.