# T4MVC Actions token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

Actions token was removed from T4MVC. So do I understand right there is no short syntax for referencing Action inside the same Controller?

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you're trying to do and why you can't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE (12/24/2011):

My bad, I wasn't thinking straight and came up the incorrect conclusion that it was obsolete, per [What is the difference between these 2 definitions in T4Mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536269/what-is-the-difference-between-these-2-definitions-in-t4mvc). While it's not needed when referring to actions from the view, it makes a nice shortcut from within the controller itself, which is why I had added that token in the first place.

Sorry about the break, I have restored the token in 2.6.67.

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

I removed it after it came up in [What is the difference between these 2 definitions in T4Mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536269/what-is-the-difference-between-these-2-definitions-in-t4mvc), and we concluded it was not needed. Let me know if you find that in some cases you cannot just omit it. If so, please update the question with specific code. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I think I've had a lightbulb moment.  @Idsa, correct me if this is wrong.  I think the issue now is that, inside a controller, you can't just say `Actions.MyAction`, you have to fully-qualify it as  `MyApp.MyController.MyAction`.  (Not such a big deal for a short namespace, but potentially big savings in one where it's deeper.)

Comment: @GalacticCowboy, you got me right. It is really not a big deal... but it was rather convenient and I often used this short syntax especially for redirects inside one controller.